# uvm_object_utils_begin fails set field after test set filed

Tags: uvm

For some reason my object at the creation time does not pick configuration passed by test. I don't see GET when I enable tracing, only SET.
I have object as following:

```
class top_env_cfg extends uvm_object;
   int set_default_env = 1;
   `uvm_object_utils_begin(top_env_cfg)
      `uvm_field_int(set_default_env,UVM_DEFAULT);
   `uvm_object_utils_end
  function new(string name = "top_env_cfg");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction
endclass
```

In my test, inside the build_phase I am doing the following:

```
uvm_config_db#(int)::set(this, "*", "set_default_env" ,0);
```

In my environment in build_phase I am creating this object as:

```
env_cfg = top_env_cfg::type_id::create("env_cfg", this);
```

After creating this object the set_default_env still 1.
What may be wrong, and how I can debug this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code that you have inside the `build_phase()` of your environment?  Where are you doing a `uvm_config_db get()` for that resource?

Comment: I don't want use uvm_config_db::get..., I am expecting that utils macro in side the object class should do get when object created. This is what happening for uvm_env. When i changed extension of the class from uvm_object to uvm_component the explicit get works fine, but still it will not get implicitly at time of creation. Here is my get :  status = uvm_config_db#(int)::get(this, "", "enb_env" , enb_env);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to understand about the "automated retrieval of config_db resources" is that it **does not** actually happen automatically.  [This Verilab paper](https://www.verilab.com/files/configdb_dvcon2014_1.pdf) explains what happens under the hood, and I am quoting the relevant section here:

> [...] one question that is often asked with respect to retrieving data is:
>   do you always have to explicitly call the get() function? The short
>   answer is that it depends. In the UVM, there are mechanisms to
>   automate the retrieval of data from the configuration database. In
>   order to have the resource automatically retrieved two things must
>   happen:
>
> - First, that resource has to be registered with the factory using the field automation macros.
> - Second, super.build_phase(phase) must be called in the build_phase() function.

The "automated" retrieval will happen when you call `super.build_phase()` from a `uvm_component`.  In the case that you are referring to in your question, you have a `uvm_object` (you don't have a UVM `build_phase`), so you would need to explicitly perform a `uvm_config get()` call in order to retrieve the resource from the database.